# spring data JPA/Hibernate. Complex cross table SQL which doesn't map to a table entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

*** Edited with possible solution - any comments ? ***

spring 4.2.5 RELEASE

I'm starting to create Java web services onto a Legacy database.

Following the spring-data JPA repository pattern creating entities which map to tables, a repository extending CrudRepository is working well.

[As described in this great tutorial](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-two-crud/)

All the examples I've seen assume simple mapping of a table to an entity.  Order -> OrderEntity, OrderLine, Customer etc.

How would you deal with read-only reporting type queries which do not fit into this pattern where the query result contains columns from many tables and use complex cross table joins.

I'm just struggling to get my head around how to deal with this scenario.

---

**Possible Solution**

I've managed to run native SQL using the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` and map the results onto a POJO using a `BeanPropertyRowMapper`

ApplicationContext class

The NamedParameterJdbcTemplate bean is defined (the rest of the beans HikariCP, JPA Session Factory, JPA Transaction Manager, DozerBean mapper have been left out for brevity)

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement

@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.savant.test.spring.donorservicejpa.dao.repository"},
        repositoryBaseClass = com.savant.test.spring.donorservicejpa.dao.repository.BaseRepositoryImpl.class )

@ComponentScan(
        {"com.savant.test.spring.donorservicejpa.dao.jdbc.repository",
         "com.savant.test.spring.donorservicejpa.dao.query.objects"})


public class ApplicationContext {

    @Bean
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

}
```

POJO for search results. No Spring annotations, just a simple class

```
package com.savant.test.spring.donorservicejpa.dao.query.objects;

public class SessionSearchResult {

    private String sessno;
    private String sesdate;
    // etc

    // setters/getters
}
```

'Repository'.  It's not actually a repository in spring terms, just an interface/class implementation

```
package com.savant.test.spring.donorservicejpa.dao.jdbc.repository;

public interface SessionSearchRepository{
    List<SessionSearchResult> findByCriteria(String searchCriteria);
}
```

Base implementation

```
package com.savant.test.spring.donorservicejpa.dao.jdbc.repository;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;

public class BaseJdbcRepositoryImpl {

    protected final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    BaseJdbcRepositoryImpl(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

}
```

Simple test implementation of the search.

```
package com.savant.test.spring.donorservicejpa.dao.jdbc.repository;


import com.savant.test.spring.donorservicejpa.dao.query.objects.SessionSearchResult;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;


@Component
public class SessionSearchRepositoryImpl extends BaseJdbcRepositoryImpl implements SessionSearchRepository {

    private static final String SESSION_SEARCH_SQL
            = "SELECT sesdet.sessno, sessdays.sesdate "
            + "FROM sesdet, sessdays "
            + "WHERE sessdays.sessno = sesdet.sessno "
            + "AND sesdet.sessno = :sessno";


    @Autowired
    public SessionSearchRepositoryImpl(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        super(jdbcTemplate);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Override
    public List<SessionSearchResult> findByCriteria(String searchCriteria) {
        Map<String, String> queryParams = new HashMap<>();

        queryParams.put("sessno", searchCriteria);
        List<SessionSearchResult> searchResults = jdbcTemplate.query(SESSION_SEARCH_SQL, queryParams,
                new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(SessionSearchResult.class));

        return searchResults;
    }
}
```

And a simple test just to run the SQL

```
@Autowired
SessionSearchRepository sessionSearchRepository;


@Test
public void a_testSessionSearch() throws Exception, Throwable {
    List<SessionSearchResult> sl =  sessionSearchRepository.findByCriteria("CA04AS");

    for (SessionSearchResult sessionSearchEntity : sl) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Create a view at the DB level and map an entity to that. Keeps all the complex DB stuff out of your code.

Comment: On a database with several hundred tables (data and reference) a view for every cross table join query is not a practical solution.  It's quite common to have a query for data display which gets descriptions from several other reference tables for example.  This is just a read-only query used to display data in the UI.  I am looking for a way within the spring-data framework to hand craft the SQL, execute it and map the results to a non @ entity POJO.

Comment: Well, I guess if you aren't dealing with entities then you'd create a bog standard repository (not extending any Spring data repository), inject the entity manager and code the necessary queries and mappings to pojos.

Comment: Yes that sounds like what I want to achieve. Do you know of any example code.  I think I'm half way there using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate, BeanPropertyRowMapper..

Comment: Possible solution added to original question.  Is this the correct way to go ?